# Return unique combinations from many to many join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, hierarchy

I have a hierarchy table with the following data :

```
SOURCE  TARGET  Level   ID
0       1       1       1
0       2       1       2
2       3       2       3
2       4       2       4
2       5       2       5
1       3       2       6
1       4       2       7
1       5       2       8
5       3       3       9
5       3       3       10
4       3       3       11
4       3       3       12
3       6       3       13
3       6       3       14
3       6       4       15
3       6       4       16
3       6       4       17
3       6       4       18
```

The SOURCE and TARGET rows are the original data and are used to connect between parents and children. for example, the third row (SOURCE 2, TARGET 3 on LEVEL 2) connects to the second row (SOURCE 0, TARGET 2 on LEVEL 1) since the Source of the first equals the target of the second. 
The ID column is added at the end using a ROW_NUMBER function and is used to give each row a unique ID.
It may be easier to understand if SOURCE is replaced with PARENT and TARGET with CHILD.

I join the table to itself in order to find the "parent". 
I want each "instance" of a "source" on each level to connect to one of its parents. It's not important which ones connect but all need to be connected and to **different** parents.

The final results should look something like this:

```
SOURCE  TARGET  Level   ID   P_ID
0       1       1       1    NULL
0       2       1       2    NULL
2       3       2       3    2
2       4       2       4    2
2       5       2       5    2
1       3       2       6    1
1       4       2       7    1
1       5       2       8    1
5       3       3       9    5
5       3       3       10   8
4       3       3       11   4
4       3       3       12   7
3       6       3       13   3
3       6       3       14   6
3       6       4       15   9
3       6       4       16   10
3       6       4       17   11
3       6       4       18   12
```

Any suggestions on how to write a good ms-sql query for this?

Comment: You'll need more data than that or any suggestion you get will not suffice when you inevitably expand with more rules.

Comment: Do you think I should show a whole example set? I have a small (full) set of data, about 18 rows. What do you think?

Comment: @Gidil, a dataset of 18 rows would be helpful.

Comment: So, basically, balance each level's "children" equally among the "parent"s at the earlier level, correct?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. I've haven't been able to verbalize it that well yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link to sample data and [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/904ca/16/0)

The query to use is below.

```
;with cte as (
  select *,rn=row_number() over (partition by level, target
                                 order by id),
           lc=count(1) over (partition by level, target)
  from tbl
)

select a.*, b.id as parent_id
from cte a
left join cte b on b.level=a.level-1
               and b.target=a.source
               and b.rn=(a.rn-1)%b.lc+1
order by id
```

1. Items are sequenced at each level/target combination
2. Children are linked to parents using by sequence, however if there are more children than parents, the MOD (%) operator takes care of going back to the first parent and continues distribution

Comment: First off, thanks for the answer. At first it looked like it would work, but I found that it doesn't really work. It connects according to level only and not according to the parent's original ID. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough on my question :-(

Comment: The third and fifth rows for example. The parent ID should be 2 in both cases (as in the fourth row) but it shows up as 1.

Comment: I think I need to edit the question to make it clearer. I'll edit it now and I hope it will answer your question.

Comment: Has been edited. Please let me know if it still needs clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Looks **very** good! I'm going to try it out on the full data set and will let you know if any problems arise. Thanks again!